# Knockout Mapping Observable not being "observed"?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/8/

I'm trying to make the side editable if I click on the text.  I'm following this example from the knockout site:

view:

```
<p>
    Name: 
    <b data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: name, click: edit">&nbsp;</b>
    <input data-bind="visible: editing, value: name, hasfocus: editing" />
</p>
<p><em>Click the name to edit it; click elsewhere to apply changes.</em></p>
```

script:

```
function PersonViewModel(name) {
    // Data
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.editing = ko.observable(false);

    // Behaviors
    this.edit = function() { this.editing(true) }
}

ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel("Bert Bertington"));
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html

When I click on the text of a "side", I hit the "edit" function, but the visibility of the divs doesn't change.  I think this is a scoping issue but I don't know how to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `hasfocus` binding is also tied to the `editable` observable. Removing this binding causes the visibility to update just fine. I'm guessing this means that Knockout is trying to set focus and failing, thus setting `editable` back to false.

Perhaps instead of using that binding, you could attach a `blur` event handler to the inputs instead, in which handler you would set `editable` to false.